# No thumb folder generate by paperclip when uploading from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following ToyPhoto model:

```
require "open-uri"
class ToyPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :toy
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => {
    :thumb => ["210x210>", :jpg]
  }

  def image_url=(value)
    self.image = open(value)
  end
end
```

When I upload a photo, I don't see the corresponding thumb folder being created. This is how I create the ToyPhoto objects:

```
params[:photos].each do |photo|
  @toy_photo = ToyPhoto.new
  @toy_photo.image_url = photo[:url]
  @toy_photo.save

  @toy.photos << @toy_photo
end
```

I do see photo being successfully uploaded to original folder, but no thumb folder created. Did I miss some configuration problem? I am suspecting that strong_parameter didn't defined when uploading from url, however I am not sure how to set strong_parameter in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem in your code is how you specify the format of the thumb style. Reading the Paperclip API showed that the proper way to do this is like so:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :thumb => ["210x210#", :jpg] }
```

Comment: thanks @amb110395, I just found the typo of style's' and the correct style definition, and fixed that but still the thumb folder is not being created yet...